# Change font size in a prespecified .sty file

Tags: fonts, size

I'm trying to change the font size of the poster template obtained from https://github.com/anishathalye/gemini/blob/master/beamerthemegemini.sty.

I want the headlines and the block font remain the same and only change the contents of the poster. However, when I chage the scale in main.txt :

```
\usepackage[size=custom,width=120,height=80,scale=1.28]{beamerposter}
```

Every scale changes including the heading. When I tried to change the font size of the heading instead of the block contents from \Huge to \LARGE :

```
\documentclass[final,30pt]{beamer}
\setbeamerfont{headline title}{size=\LARGE,series=\bfseries}
```

The title becomes too small. Is there a way to change only the font size of the contents? Using pt does not seem to work. I want to change the font size to 30pt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `\setbeamerfont{block body}{family=\Lato,size={\fontsize{30}{36}}}` in your preamble.

And also add `\setbeamerfont{enumerate item}{size={\fontsize{30}{36}}}` to expand the numbers in the numbered list to the same size.

**Before**

[image: c]

**After**

[image: Z]